# AzureWebApp@1 deployment wwwroot empty

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-appservice

I have a .net core application which I am deploying with an Azure Pipeline to an App Service.

The pipeline completes successfully (and creates a build artifact which is valid) , but when I FTP onto the App Service, wwwroot is empty!! In the deployments folder, there is a new folder which includes logs stating success.

Further, in the Azure Portal, App Service Deployment center confirms a successful deployment.

ODDLY, deployment center renders 1 slot which references the wrong branch (I historically accidentally clicked sync on the UI), however the referenced build id and commit id are correct and do come from the correct branch!!

The logs in the deployments folder claim success!

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      version: '6.0.x'  
    
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: 'thisisnumero' # A series of numbers and letters
      projects: 'source/ui/code/code.sln'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
      displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
      projects: 'source/ui/code/code.sln'
      
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: True
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: True

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
      artifactName: 'code'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'V2B Web App Configurator'
      #appType: 'webAppLinux'
      appName: 'videotobricks'
      package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

When I try to visit my app its running and error logs reference C:\home\site\wwwroot\

Why does the FTP site show an empty folder??

Comment: Did you ever fix this, I am having the exact same issue